# parse string with potentially 2 occurrences of the same string

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on parsing an address string and have found that sometimes the street name contains a word that is also a valid city name.  I want to be sure that any second occurrence of city name is always matched to the last group in the regex and the first group in the regex is treated as optional.

Here is some sample input:

```
123 SUNNYSIDE AVENUE BROOKLYN
59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN
59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN 10038
39-076 46 STREET SUNNYSIDE
39-076 46 STREET SUNNYSIDE 11104
59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN NY USA
```

Ideally the regex groups returned for these would be as follows:

```
(123 )(SUNNYSIDE)( AVENUE )(BROOKLYN)
(59 MAIDEN LANE )(null)(null)(MANHATTAN)
(59 MAIDEN LANE )(null)(null)(MANHATTAN)
(39-076 46 STREET )(null)(null)(SUNNYSIDE)
(39-076 46 STREET )(null)(null)(SUNNYSIDE)
(59 MAIDEN LANE )(null)(null)(MANHATTAN)
```

For the cities, I have a list (dumbed down for this example) in a regex group like this:

```
(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)
```

My starting regex was this:

```
(.*?)(?:\W*)(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)(?:.*)
```

But of course that outputs:

```
(123)(SUNNYSIDE)
```

I'm trying to expand it to support the cases mentioned above, but everything I've tried thus far to match 1 or 2 cities will always match the first city it finds as the last group and ignore the remainder.

There are a lot of special issues with address parsing, but right now I'm focused on solving just this one particular case.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I added the "59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN NY USA" example after the original posting.  I'm still hoping to find a solution that doesn't depend on a zip or nothing falling at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample output is confusing.  The first line implies that you want to break the street address down to its individual components, but in the rest of the lines it's all bunched together.  I would expect the desired result to be either:

```
"123 SUNNYSIDE AVENUE", "BROOKLYN"
"59 MAIDEN LANE", "MANHATTAN"
"59 MAIDEN LANE", "MANHATTAN"
"39-076 46 STREET", "SUNNYSIDE"
"39-076 46 STREET", "SUNNYSIDE"
"59 MAIDEN LANE", "MANHATTAN"
```

...or:

```
"123", "SUNNYSIDE", "AVENUE", "BROOKLYN"
"59", "MAIDEN", "LANE", "MANHATTAN"
"59", "MAIDEN", "LANE", "MANHATTAN"
"39-076", "46", "STREET", "SUNNYSIDE"
"39-076", "46", "STREET", "SUNNYSIDE"
"59", "MAIDEN", "LANE", "MANHATTAN"
```

In either case, I would start by matching it with this regex:

```
^(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)\s+(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)
```

The first group is greedy, so it will initially consume all but the last word of the address string.  If the last word is not a city name (that is, it doesn't match the `(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)` group), the first group "gives up" one word at a time until the second group *does* match.

Assuming the string actually contains a city name, and the name is included in the second group's subexpression, it will be captured in group #2.  Group #1 will contain the whole street address; if you want it broken up as shown above, you can split it on whitespace.

**EDIT:** Here's some sample code to demonstrate.  Note especially the use of `find()` instead of `matches()`.  The behavior of Java's `matches()` method surprises many people, and it occurred to that it might be part of the problem here.  In a nutshell, `find()` is why I had to add `^` the beginning of the regex, and why I *didn't* have to add `.*` to the end. ;)

```
String[] ss = {
    "123 SUNNYSIDE AVENUE BROOKLYN",
    "59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN",
    "59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN 10038",
    "39-076 46 STREET SUNNYSIDE",
    "39-076 46 STREET SUNNYSIDE 11104",
    "59 MAIDEN LANE MANHATTAN NY USA"
};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s+(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("");

for (String s : ss)
{
  if (m.reset(s).find())
  {
    System.out.printf("%naddr: '%s'%ncity: '%s'%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
  }
}
```

output:

```
addr: '123 SUNNYSIDE AVENUE'
city: 'BROOKLYN'

addr: '59 MAIDEN LANE'
city: 'MANHATTAN'

addr: '59 MAIDEN LANE'
city: 'MANHATTAN'

addr: '39-076 46 STREET'
city: 'SUNNYSIDE'

addr: '39-076 46 STREET'
city: 'SUNNYSIDE'

addr: '59 MAIDEN LANE'
city: 'MANHATTAN'
```

Comment: You're right, I don't care about separating out the beginning parts, I just want the "city" and the rest.  This is working for the problem as I have described it.

Comment: +1 - should work most of the time! The only potential snag is when/if someone puts something like `123 SUNNYSIDE AVENUE` (i.e. without a city) - it will match with `123` and `SUNNYSIDE`, then drop the `AVENUE` part - changing the `*` to a `+` should fix this, by requiring 2 instances of "non-whitespace followed by whitespace" (presumably a number and name or at least two words) at the risk of excluding things like `MAYOR MANHATTAN NY` - not sure how likely this is to be an issue...?

Comment: Ahh, but what about `123 LOWER SUNNYSIDE AVENUE`?  :P  But seriously, if you can assume the city name is present, everything else will sort itself out.  And if you *can't* assume that, it becomes a completely different question--one I probably won't try to answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Down this road lies madness. Addresses are just not parseable. In your case, you can tell the regex engine that it only may match a ZIP code or end-of-string after your city name. That should work:

```
^(.*?)\s+(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)\s*(\d*)$
```

Comment: I agree that madness lies ahead.  What if I want to allow for unknown content at the end, not just zip?  The user could enter anything.  Maybe they enter this...  59 Maiden Lane Manhattan NY USA

Comment: more context would be supremely useful... Are these entered into a web form, one at a time? If so, this is nearly impossible, as users are ingenious and indeed often disingenuous... Is this from a long list of addresses in a file? If so, are they always one address per line? in short: grrrr........

Comment: They will be entered into a web form.  I'm somewhat new to regex, so although my examples are definitely limited given the scope of what I am trying to support, I mainly wanted just to learn what would be recommended for the regex for this very specific set of data and this very specific case.  I will obviously require a MUCH broader solution to the overall problem.

Comment: @SarahHaskins I thought that might be the case, so if you have not already, please indicate whether or not my answer was helpful (comment, vote, or however you see fit) - I'm currently bemused as to the downvote!

Comment: -1 answer the question, or put your opinion in comments - those can can upvoted too, ya know! if you are going to tell someone they shouldn't be doing something they want to do, but it is still possible, then tell them _how_ it is possible (which is an answer), _then_ tell them not to do it.

Comment: @Code Jockey, for the record, I was the one who upvoted your answer. And I did provide an answer that would match the last occurrence of the city name, but I'm simply warning that this "solution" will fail just as all other solutions will fail eventually because addresses are just unparseable.

Answer (score 0):

Given your somewhat limited set of examples (considering just how complex addresses can be, *and even more so when compressed to a single line* ***and even more so when punctuation is removed***), and not really knowing how you're using all of this anyways, I think the regular expression you just might need is the following:

```
^([\w -]*?)(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)(?:[ 0-9-]*)$
```

Broken down, this expression says:

```
^                                # Assert at beginning
(                                # Capture the following
   [\w -]                        #    Match letters, numbers, [space]'s and hyphens
   *?                            #    ...any number of times, but be reluctant
)                                # <end capture>
(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)   # Capture one of these three strings
(?:                              # Match but do not group the following
   [ 0-9-]*                      #    [space]'s, numbers, and hyphens
)                                # <end match>
$                                # Assert end of line
```

This captures the following groups:

```
(123 SUNNYSIDE AVENUE )     (BROOKLYN)
(59 MAIDEN LANE )           (MANHATTAN)
(59 MAIDEN LANE )           (MANHATTAN)
(39-076 46 STREET )         (SUNNYSIDE)
(39-076 46 STREET )         (SUNNYSIDE)
```

If you actually want to identify street names and types (like `SUNNYSIDE` and `AVENUE` as distinct groups), *but only when they are the same as city names*, that will require a more complex expression.

**EDIT:**
Your expression, when broken down, says:

```
(.*?)                            # Match any character except newline, any number of times, but be reluctant
(?:\W*)                          # Match but do not group any non-word character, any number of times
(MANHATTAN|BROOKLYN|SUNNYSIDE)   # Match one of these three strings
(?:.*)                           # Match but do not group any number of characters except newline
```

Your expression, as written, would match anything it could, up to a space(non-word character), then match the space, then try to match what follows the space with one of the city names. If that worked, it would then match anything else on the line. If it did not work, it would go back and match the space previously mentioned, then any characters up to the next non-word character. Then it would match the space, and continue looping until it finds a city name.

The `(?:)` construct around the `\W*` is essentially meaningless, as the `\W*` is a single match, repeated any number of times.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not the most efficient expression in the world (due to backtracking needed), but is probably the only way (or along the same lines as the only way) to get what you want with a single expression

Comment: really? why a down-vote? Does my answer does not answer the question asked? Please explain

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either.  You and Tim posted virtually the same regex at the same time, so why should only you get DV'd?  You even supplied a breakdown of the regex!  Though I have a problem with the phrase "Match but do not group": you *are* grouping, you just aren't *capturing*.  Also, the non-capturing parens in your regex are just as useless as the ones in the OP's. ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore good point on the non-capturing groups - mistake made due to fatigue and my never-ending quest to provide detailed answers as quickly as possible :D --- Also, while I see your point, and I suppose you are technically correct, the "Match but do not group ..." comment is shorter than "Match in a group but do not capture into a matching group" and is still pretty close to the truth... either way, in my case it was unnecessary! and to make it worse, it's not what the asker needed!